# (gdb) p/x equivalent in gdb python script?

Tags: python, gdb, gdb-python

the main structure is

```
struct my_struct 
{
   int x; 
   void* md_template;
   void* md_capture_buff;
   ....
};
```

When i am doing

`(gdb) p ((struct my_struct *)dev_base->next->priv)`

The output is like this

```
$1 = {
 x= 15 '\017'
 md_template = ,
 md_capture_buff =
}
```

And when i am doing it with p/x:

`(gdb) p/x ((struct my_struct *)dev_base->next->priv)`

The output is like this

```
$1 = {
 x= 0xf;
 md_template =0x410027001a50 ,
 md_capture_buff = 0x41002c0c5490
}
```

**In gdb-python:**

`python val = gdb.parse_and_eval('((struct my_struct *)dev_base->next->priv)')`

`python print val`

The output is:

```
$1 = {
 x= 15 '\017'
 md_template = ,
 md_capture_buff =
}
```

So how to write equivalent to p/x in gdb-python? or how to get the address of 'md_capture_buff' in python script as `python val = gdb.parse_and_eval('((struct my_struct *)dev_base->next->priv)').address` is not prining the address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have "set print address" off.  I wouldn't do this.  It's arguably a bug that the str operator is respecting this setting.

There isn't a good way to reproduce "p/x" other than just invoking it directly.  See gdb.execute.

You can get the value of any field using [].  Like

```
val = something['fieldname']
```

It's usually better, IMO, to use the API rather than parse_and_eval.  That is, you can cast, look up fields, etc, directly from Python.

Comment: @tromey, Thanks. But while traversing a structure if an array occurs as a member, then how to print the values of whole array in hex (more readable form). it is possible only with `p/x`. but we can not use `gdb.execute('p/x <array>')` in the middle of traversal. I want to implement this in this script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787289/gdb-python-parsing-structures-each-field-and-print-them-with-proper-value-if . Please let me know if there is a way to do this. can we control printing arrays as the pointers are done in this script ?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid parse_and_eval() but I'm not sure how to read a structure pointer directly without it. What API can I use to avoid using parse_and_eval(), assuming the OP's question?

Comment: There are a number of methods on `gdb.Value` that you'd use.  You can use `dereference` to dereference a pointer, use `["fieldname"]` to get a field from a structure (or a pointer-to-structure -- so often you don't even need `dereference`), and use `cast` to change the type.